# Testing Angular controller and spying on a mocked service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I'm learning how to test in Angular and followed a tutorial that showed how to mock out the services that your controller uses. Can't seem to figure out why it isn't working so I'm turning here for help. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong and how to get it working would be greatly appreciated.

Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.

```
// Controller

'use strict';

angular.module('tikrApp')
  .controller('MessageCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'messageService', function ($scope, $state, messageService) {

    /**
     * Set $state on the scope to access it in the views
     */
    $scope.$state = $state;

   /**
    * Fetches a messages list that belongs to the authenticated user
    */
   $scope.inbox = function () {
     messageService.inbox().then(function (messages) {
       $scope.messages = messages;
     });
   };

  /**
   * Fetches a message
   */
  $scope.show = function (message) {
    messageService.update(message, { read: true }).then(function (result) {
      if (result) {
        $scope.message = message;
        $scope.message.read = true;
      }
    });
  };

  /**
   * Prioritizes the message for the user
   */
  $scope.starred = function (message) {
    messageService.update(message, { starred: true }).then(function (result) {
      if (result) message.starred = true;
    });
  };

  /**
   * Creates a new private message to a user
   */
  $scope.create = function (newMessage) {
    messageService.create(newMessage).then(function () {
      $scope.messages.push(newMessage);
      $state.transitionTo('inbox.messages');
    }, function () {
      $state.transitionTo('inbox.messages.create');
    });
  };

  $scope.inbox();
  // $state.transitionTo('inbox.messages');

}]);

// Spec

'use strict';

describe('Controller: MessageCtrl', function () {

  var scope;
  var messageService;

  beforeEach(function () {

    var mockMessageService = {};
    module('tikrApp', function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('messageService', mockMessageService);
    });

    inject(function ($q) {
      mockMessageService.messages = [
        { to: '123', from: '123', title: 'Title 1', content: 'Content 1', read: false },
        { to: '123', from: '123', title: 'Title 2', content: 'Content 2', read: false },
        { to: '123', from: '123', title: 'Title 3', content: 'Content 3', read: false }
      ];

      mockMessageService.inbox = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.resolve(this.messages);
        return defer.promise;
      };

      mockMessageService.create = function (newMessage) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.resolve();
        return defer.promise;
      };

    });

  });

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _messageService_) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    messageService = _messageService_;
    $controller('MessageCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      messageService: messageService
    });

    scope.$digest();

  }));

  it('should list all messages in the users inbox', function () {
    // tried this way
    spyOn(scope, 'inbox');
    // and this way
    spyOn(messageService, 'inbox');
    expect(messageService.inbox).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Comment: Can you move the spyOn before $controller creation or before digest. I am thinking by the time you setup the spy the calls have already completed.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work @Chandermani. Still results in the same error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's how I usually unit test controller-service communication. I find this approach easier:

```
'use strict';
describe('countryController', function () {
    var scope;
    var searchService;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        mockSearchService();
        createController($controller);
    }));

    it('loads flights after view is shown', function () {
        scope.loadFlights();
        expect(searchService.loadFlights).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    function mockSearchService() {
        searchService = jasmine.createSpyObj('searchService', ['loadFlights']);
    }

    function createController($controller) {
        $controller('countryController', {
            $scope: scope,
            searchService: searchService
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Daniil, I'm now receiving a different error with your provided suggestion. I think what is happening now is that scope.inbox() gets called but is not using a mock/spy version of my messageService.inbox. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance. 

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'messageService.inbox().then')

Comment: That is normal as messageService.inbox() now is mocked object now. The way of fixing it is injecting $q in your beforeEach and setting your resolved value in your test:

    it('test', function () {
        var messages = [{name: '1'}];
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        messageService.inbox.andReturn(deferred.promise);

        scope.inbox();
        deferred.resolve(messages);
        scope.$apply();

        expect(scope.messages).toEqual(messages);
    });